# Unable to run second instance of GlassFish

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to setup a pipeline following the guide on [this](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/continuous-integration-and-deployment-using-git-maven-jenkins-and-glassfish/) website.

I setup the glassfish servers as shown in the guide. When I run one of the servers there is no problem. But as I run a second server it gives the following error:

http://pastebin.com/jPm7gfGt

For comparison the first server I run gives the following output:

http://pastebin.com/xwqF5v62

I'm a bit confused on what to do next. It seems a port is in use?

Answer (score 0):

Can You try to create domains steb-by-step. I.e create first one - production than start it with 
asadmin start-domain production. 
Than create next one.
In that case glassfish can detect already used ports and select other numbers in second and next domains.

Hope this helps